# Different Chromecast icons set

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

In the cast [resources page](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads), a link to a [icons set](https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastIcons.zip) is available:

[image: GoogleCastIcons.zip]
Nevertheless, this one is completely different to the provided by the [v7 mediarouter library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-mediarouter) although is supposed to be the same as the included there:

[image: support_r21.0.3 mediarouter drawables]
What's the point of that? Any use guidelines for this zip? 
On the other hand, this zip contains two different image sizes (24dp and 48dp). There's no clue of what it should be used for.

Answer (score 1):

As told by a Google guy:

> Please use the new cast icon from https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/downloads for the iOS app.
>   The icon in the mediarouter library will be updated alongside the new upcoming Google Play Services API release and will be therefore included automatically in your Android app.

...So lets stick with the latest version of Android library icons.